# RoR 2.3.11 and Rspec 1.2.9 ... adding tests to existing project: tests exist however they're ignored

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

Hey all this is where I'm at:

```
$ spec spec/

Finished in 0.002031 seconds

0 examples, 0 failures
```

HOWEVER.  I've got my first few tests I've written and placed them in /spec/controllers/citations_controller_spec.rb

and added a puts in the above spec to verify that its actually being executed on the use of:

```
spec spec/
```

here are the contents of citations_controller_spec.rb ( it has existing tests ) :

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe CitationsController do
  describe "GET 'home'" do
    it "should be successful" do
      get 'home'
      response.should be_success
    end
    it "should have the right title" do
      get 'home'
      response.should have_tag("title",
                               "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Home")
    end
  end

  describe "GET 'contact'" do
    it "should be successful" do
      get 'contact'
      response.should be_success
    end
    it "should have the right title" do
      get 'contact'
      response.should have_tag("title",
                               "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Contact")
    end
  end

  describe "GET 'about'" do
    it "should be successful" do
      get 'about'
      response.should be_success
    end
    it "should have the right title" do
      get 'about'
      response.should have_tag("title",
                               "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | About")
    end
  end
end
```

But as shown in the first code bit ...

```
0 examples, 0 failures
```

.. so anyone happen to know whats going on here?

Comment: Does `rake spec` provide the same output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
spec spec/controllers/citations_controller_spec.rb
```

to run one test file. Or

```
rake test
```

to run all tests. Do you see any test dots or examples now?

Comment: I tried running the individual tests .. but the $ rake test did exactly what I needed!

Comment: nope cancel that ... turns our that "rake test" runs a completely different set of tests than the ones that I've actually written. =/

Comment: Try using `rake spec` instead of `rake spec/` please.

Comment: http://pastie.org/5129007 so its saying all these migrations should be run .. I'm hoping these migrations are modifying only the test DB ... right?

Comment: Hmm, no, this means your development database is not up-to-date and you should migrate this, not your test database. Can you check, if your database.yml points to the right development database? If you run `rake db:migrate`, it will modify your development database. So if you don't want this, don't run the migrations. But then I'd wonder why your development database is out-of-date.